# Возможно записать результат работы java программы в *.txt используя bat-файл?

Tags: bat, java

Здравствуйте!

Нужно запустить jar файл через bat-файл, перехватить результат выполнения jar и записать его в txt. Возможно ли такое???
Спасибо.

Comment: Про перенаправление потоков ввода/вывода слышали?

Comment: Слышал, потому и хочу узнать можно ли в bat такое осуществить???  Можете привести пример, ссылку на удачные примеры?

Comment: @Alerr, для избавления от каши в голове рекомендую к прочтению [классический мануал](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html), спасший немало неофитов от этой напасти.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ не холивара ради, а исключительно пользы для - позвольте полюбопытствовать, а почему вы закрыли этот вопрос? Насколько я могу судить, он не нарушает никаких правил форума и с этой точки зрения вполне корректен. Тот факт, что ТС не разбирается в простых вещах, вряд ли может быть таковой причиной - все же форум существует в том числе и для того, чтобы помочь людям в них разобраться

Comment: @DreamChild я просто хотел оградить ТС от бездумного минусования - вот и все. А ответы ему уже написаны, так что холивар уже был неуместен.

Answer (score 1):

.

```
 java -jar program.jar > output.txt
```

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, в документе пусто. В консольке пишет что не может найти main class.

Comment: @Alerr программа использует стандартный поток вывода?

Comment: Точно не могу сказать, я провожу junit тест, результат теста выводится в окне output в eclips.
Вот дословно: Error: Could not find or load main class standart2.Main

Comment: @Alerr
Если какие-то результаты выводятся в консоль, то использует. Есть два потока - стандартный поток вывода (System.out) и поток вывода ошибок (System.err).


Вероятно, вы неправильно запускаете программу. Делайте это так, как делали раньше, когда работало, в конце добавляйте > text_file.txt, все будет путем.

Comment: Оно с консоли еще никогда не запускалось, решил научиться запускать(через бат) и вот, нашел на сайтах что что-то с classpath не так, а по сути не могу понять что ему не хватает(

Comment: до юниттеста еще далеко) вам бы смоук пройти :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Пишется обработчик, который, например, принимает аргументы командной строки в `public static void main(String[] args)`.

По типу:

```
if(args.length > 0)

{

PrintStream st = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));

System.setErr(st);

System.setOut(st);

}
```

2. В bat'нике прописывается что-то вроде

```
java -jar ИмяКлассаПриложения.jar 1
```